# Combining QuerySets based on a shared column - django

Tags: python, django

**Models.py**

```
class sells(models.Model):
    #unimportant stuff here
    type = ...
    supplier = ...
    user = ...
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class sale_items(models.Model):
    item_id = models.OnetoOneField(sells, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    item_name = ...
    description = ... 
    #other unimportant stuff
```

So I'm trying to implement search, and right now I have it so that search returns any information found in sale_items such as name and description. But I also need to output an items type and supplier which is in the sells model. Essentially I am trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT A.item_id, A.item_name ... B.type, B.supplier ... 
FROM sale_items A, sells B
WHERE A.item_id = B.item_id
```

**Views.py**

```
def SearchView(request):
    query_results = sale_items.objects.filter(Q(item_name__icontains=search)
                      Q(description__icontains=search))
    return render(request, 'db/search_results.html', {'query_results':query_results})
```

I did not include the code for the variable search, but it is the text that was entered into the search bar. query_results is correct and in my template (search_results.html) I use a for loop to print out the item name and description.

I would like to somehow also include the information in the sells model that corresponds to the same item_id. I've been trying a lot of different things to try and get this to work and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
query_results = sale_items.objects.filter(Q(...) | Q(sells__type__icontains=search))
```

Comment: The type and supplier/user aren't related to the search. The search returns items based on name and description. Each item has an id that is in sells and sale_items. So I need to use that id to get corresponding info from both models.